# Jquery clicking on label firing events on other controls with same name

Tags: jquery, click

I have the below code where I am trying to show alert when I click on label. But Even input items are firing because of same for attribute. How can make label click event fire? I tried some thing like 
$('label[for="CurrentMonth"]').click(function (e) { but it did not work. Any suggestions

```
<label class="labelHelp" for="CurrentMonth">Current Month</label>
    <input name="CurrentMonth" class="text-box single-line valid" id="CurrentMonth" type="text" value="February, 2015">

    $('[for="CurrentMonth"]').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert("I clicked only on label");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with using return false.

```
    $('[for="CurrentMonth"]').click(function (e) {
                alert("I clicked only on label");
                return false;
            });
```

check this link for more understanding:
http://saswal.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/event-preventdefault-event-stoppropagation-return-false-event-stopimmediatepropagation/

Answer (score 2):

Your code as it stands should work. Your selection should only match an element with the for attribute set to "CurrentMonth". This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8gs3Lvf/) shows that clicking on the Current Month label causes the click to fire, but clicking on the input text, or a different label does not.

```
<label class="labelHelp" for="CurrentMonth">Current Month</label>
<input name="CurrentMonth" class="text-box single-line valid" id="CurrentMonth" type="text" value="February, 2015">
<br/>        
<label class="labelHelp" for="NextMonth">Next Month</label>
<input name="Nextonth" class="text-box single-line valid" id="NextMonth" type="text" value="March, 2015">     

$('label[for="CurrentMonth"]').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     alert("I clicked only on label");
});
```

Can you reproduce the problem online?

Answer (score 1):

Well I have checked and test your code it is working perfectly. you can also check either you you have not put all you code or missing something.

Please post your all code and see this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5drc0xze/

HTML

```
<label class="labelHelp" for="CurrentMonth">Current Month</label>
<input name="CurrentMonth" class="text-box single-line valid" id="CurrentMonth" type="text" value="February, 2015">
```

JS:

```
$('[for="CurrentMonth"]').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("I clicked only on label");
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone who provided answers close to my problem solution. Answers provided by Techies here are almost good, but the one which solved my problem is adding return false to which I marked correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the event handling inside document.getready method you code itself works like charm , check here http://jsfiddle.net/0vn60ccL/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('[for="CurrentMonth"]').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("I clicked only on label");
    });
});
```

Current Month